# adding a mechanism to filter output in a system based on inheritance

Tags: c++

my question is about the way to do in object oriented solution.
i used to work in C, now i'm finding some diffuculties to think object, my solutions are C style.
the problem is :

we have a class A, and a multitude of children Classes B,C,D,E....
every one of these children classe, calculates a number of values (one class may calculate, 5 values, the other 10 ....)
the need, is to add a mechanism fot the user, to demand only the values he needs, for example, the class B calculates 10 values, the user can demand only 3.
the solution has to be generalised for all the children.

the solution i proposed is c style.
adding an int x in class A and a pointer to an array of string
defining in each child class an enum of values calculated by this class.
in child class constructor, we update x by x|= (1<< tous les enum) and the pointer to the array of string will have strings in the same order of the enum (for example enum {monday, tuesday} , the array will {"monday", "tusday"}.
and i present fonctions in class A for activating/desactivating values.

what do u think, can any one improve, or propose a more object oriented solution.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad, and you're asking for us to review your algorithm rather than solve a specific problem. Is there a specific problem that you're trying to fix?

Comment: Yes, i just cited the need, and i talked about the solution i proposed just to explain more the need, the question is about "how is the best manner to resolve this.my solution seems to be C stype (i never think about classes, tmplates, stl in first)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a virtual member function in the parent class. The "array subscript operator" seems appropriate for getting stored values:

```
A {
    virtual const T& operator[](std::size_t index) const = 0;
};
```

A user can then demand exactly as many values as they need and the children can implement the function in a way appropriate for each of them.

`T` is of course the type of the values stored in the objects.Depending on the type, or how it's used, returning a copy might be more appropriate.

If all the children store the values in the same way, a vector for example, then it would be simpler to put the vector in `A` and make the member function non-virtual. That way the children need only take care of populating the vector with the results of the calculation.

However, given the description, I see no need for object oriented solution at all. A purely functional approach might be much simpler. You could have functions `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, ... which return a vector of values.

Comment: thx for your answer. but if i understand well your solution, the user does B[3], means that he needs only three values, but which values ?
the user have to specify which values he needs, that's why i thought about enum exported, so he will have a list, choose what he likes, and the necessary will be done

Comment: Actually, `B[3]` would mean that user needs 4 values and they would specifically use the values from 0 to 3. But if you need a mapping from a name to a value, then an array is probably not ideal. There's not enough information in the question to determine what would be a good design for such mapping. Some things that you should consider are: Does a value `z` from class `B` represent the same thing as value `z` from `C`. Why does the class hierarchy exist? What is `A` used for?